# Design pattern about awaiting several tasks at the same time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Here is my approach. I have several `IEventProviders`,

```
interface IEventProvider
{
    Task<Event> GetEvent();
}
```

Then I got a container class to wrap them, and keep calling and awaiting the `GetEvent()` to wait for next Event, e.g. socket async receiving, timer ticks, etc.

```
class EventProviderContainer : IEventProvider
{
    private IEventProvider[] _providers;
    private Task<Event>[] _tasks;

    public EventProviderContainer(params IEventProvider[] providers)
    {
        _providers = providers;
    }

    public async Task<Event> GetEvent()
    {
        // Fill the _tasks first time we call the method.
        if (_tasks == null)
            _tasks = (from p in _providers select p.GetEvent()).ToArray();

        Task<Event> task = await Task<Event>.WhenAny(_tasks);

        // Get the provider index whose previous task is done.
        int index = Array.IndexOf(_tasks, task);
        // put next event of the provider into array.
        _tasks[index] = _providers[index].GetEvent();

        return await task;
    }
}
```

I think it is a bit of ugly. Is it a better way to do it?

Comment: This looks strange. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Do all of the providers have infinite number of events? If not, how will you find out that a provider is done?

Comment: "Event streams" like this are usually a better fit for TPL Dataflow or Rx, and it would be more natural to treat your event providers as "pushers" instead of having to repeatedly "pull" the events from them.

Comment: @svick, yes, they all do have infinite number of events.

Comment: @StephenCleary Good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one event for each provider at a time then I recommend you check out the [Processing tasks as they complete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx) MSDN article which includes an `Interleaved` method. This method takes a collection of tasks and returns a new array of tasks that will yield in order of completion.

On the other hand, if you want to continuously receive events from each provider as they arrive, then I recommend you look at the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) project from Microsoft.

Using Rx, your event provider interface would become something like:

```
public interface IEventProvider
{
    IObservable<Event> OnEvent();
}
```

Your container provider would then use the [Observable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.merge.aspx) extension method to combine the events of each child provider.

```
return _providers.Select(provider => provider.OnEvent()).Merge();
```

To actually receive the events, you subscribe to the observable by attaching a callback delegate that's executed each time a new event is available.

```
var provider = new EventProviderContainer(
    new TestEventProvider("a", 1000),
    new TestEventProvider("b", 1300),
    new TestEventProvider("c", 1600));
provider.OnEvent().Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The above example uses a test event provider that returns a continuous stream of events at the given period in milliseconds using the [Observable.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.timer.aspx) extension method.

```
return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_period))
                 .Select(i => new TestEvent(_name, i));
```

Comment: How would you use that when you have multiple “streams” of `Task`s? (Which is what the question is about.)

Answer (score 2):

For a task that is actually not that straightforward, your code is quite short and understandable and personally I don't think it's ugly.

I don't think you're going to find a significantly better way to write this code, unless you want to change your whole interface. The only thing I would change is to move initializing `_tasks` to the constructor (but maybe you have a reason for that).

But I agree with Stephen's comment that for events, using “push” semantics is usually more appropriate than “pull”. And for that, Rx (`IObservable<Event>`) or TPL Dataflow (`ISourceBlock<Event>`) would be very useful. In both cases, writing `EventProviderContainer` would be relatively simple. Which one of the two is the better choice depends on how are you going to work with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct code for what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
    public async Task<Event> GetEvent()
    {
        // Fill the _tasks first time we call the method.
        if (_tasks == null)
            _tasks = (from p in _providers select p.GetEvent()).ToArray();


        return await await Task<Event>.WhenAny(_tasks);
    }
```

the `await await` seems a bit strange but since `WhenAny()` returns a `Task<Task<T>>` it must be correct.

Comment: But this won't work the same as the original code. And the original code already has two `await`s.

Comment: Sorry, in the orignal code, I updates the provider in the array for next task after its one task in done.